# Grayed-out class methods in Visual Studio drop-down menu

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

What does it mean when a class method is grayed out in the drop-down menu above the text editor? I'm working in VS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the method is defined in a file other than the one you're working in.

Answer (score 2):

It means that that member is defined in a different file.  (using a `partial` class)

This usually happens with the `InitializeComponent` method, which is defined in `FileName.Designer.cs`